# How can I identify the minimum value in a numpy array, excluding the diagonal zeros?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
    >>> x
    array([[ 0,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 6,  0,  8,  9],
           [ 1,  2,  0, -9]
           [ -9, 4,  3,  0])
```

I want to be able to identify -9 as the min(x), not 0.

Thanks

Comment: what have you even tried ?

Comment: There are two errors in your code.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the diagonal to the maximum value of its `dtype`. For floating point types, that would be `np.inf`, but for integers, you have to work a little harder.

   ```
   x[np.diag_indices_from(x)] = np.iinfo(x.dtype).max
   ```
2. Take the `min`.
3. Set the diagonal back to zero.

Comment: @unutbu: actually I'd use `np.inf` then.

Answer (score 0):

Since `-9 < 0 x.min()` should work without any trickery. You only need to worry if you min won't be negative.